What (else) can cause the ratio of hits over pageviews to vary per country and what can I / do I need to do about it?
I naively expected the ratio of hits and pageviews to be fairly constant.
It should be if all requests were for pages and the software used (browser) took care of requesting the files/resources needed to show it.
However, the ratio varies quite a lot between countries.

Which tells me that some countries access more files directly than other countries.
Causes I came up with:

deep links from other sites
image searches
PDFs coming up in search results
scraper sites


What else w/could result in requesting individual files directly?
Is that a cause for concern?
What can I do about it?

Note: I have tried a plugin (WP) to block direct requests but my attempts at configuring it were either ineffective or too strict and breaking my own site.

Have you looked at what URLs they are requesting?
Sites tend to get a lot of traffic from bots trying to sniff out what software you're using.  They'll do that by going to things like JavaScript files used by plug-ins directly, and seeing if it returns anything. Presumably they'll keep a database of sites that use such plug-ins, ready for if an exploit is discovered.
Security is always a concern with WordPress, as people tend to add far too many plug-ins, and don't always review and patch them.

Gosh. Never occurred to me that this is how they find vulnerable sites. Thanks! Seeing a few of what you describe in the log for a single day. From China and from multiple Azure IPs. I do keep WP and all active themes and plugins up-to-date and delete the ones I no longer use. Used to be a software/web developer/architect, so not naive in that respect :) Considering to ditch WP as I no longer update the software site, so it could be turned into a static one.
